# WinSCP alternative for Ubuntu that has sudo privilege

Tags: server, sudo, sftp

I have been using WinSCP to transfer files (php) to Ubuntu web server. I've used windows for dev work and then moved to web server for deployment. Different platforms isn't ideal (albeit I hardy ever had any issues) still want to change that now (upgrading server to 16.04 and php7 + other things). Therefore I'm looking for an replacement of WinSCP. The good thing (or bad depending on how you view it) was that I could log in with sudo and have no issue with uploading files to www directory.

eg. https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su

Can I achieve this with filezilla? If not how could that be done with file manager for example nautilus? Other alternative?

Comment: Do you need a Windows program?

Comment: No a Ubuntu program or more specific Lubuntu as I'm switching dev from win to lubuntu.

Comment: You can do the same with a file manager, like nautilus. It can connect to remote servers.

Comment: "Therefore I'm looking for an replacement of WinSCP" naah. command line "scp" for the win (pun intended!). "winscp" is nothing than a fork of our own "scp". "that I could log in with sudo and have no issue with uploading files to www directory. " I consider that bad behaviour :-(